# OLEDB Wait Type and Functions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, waits

Is there any relationship between the OLEDB Wait Type and functions? Trying to troubleshoot why I would have 77% of my waits as OLEDB wait type when we have no linked servers. I have a vendor database with a high number of both Table-valued functions and Scalar-valued functions and was curious if they could at all be related to the OLEDB wait type.

Most of the documentation I have found points to Linked Server queries for this wait type, but that's not the case for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OLEDB waits cover a variety of states, including (but not limited too) client-side profiler traces, some DBCC commands, materialisation of DMVs, possibly some full-text functions in 2005 (IIRC, most have been split out to FT specific waits in 2008) and also linked server queries as you mentioned.

I'm not aware of UDF functions inherently resulting in OLEDB waits, unless they are performing one of the actions I mentioned above.

Rather than looking at the raw percentage wait time attributed to OLEDB, have you checked the average wait time per wait? It may prove to be so low as to be insignificant.

Comment: You're exactly right, the average wait time per wait is 5.2 milliseconds - not long at all. Thanks for the additional info on OLEDB, too.